# Java GSON serialization with variable Type

Tags: java, variables, serialization, types, gson

I will have to explain my usecase first:
In the application I am developing I have a "Property System" for saving, loading & transmitting variables.

This system creates property objects which store following information:
Object value;
Type valueType;

During runtime, the "value" variable is accessed for setting and getting.

When the application needs to save properties to the hard drive (for example for shutdown) it serializes the "value" variable with GSON and saves it to a file.
Also the "valueType" variable is saved as string via "valueType.toString()".
Example output: "java.lang.String" or "java.util.List<java.lang.String>"

When the application then gets started again, it loads the properties from their files by first loading the "valueType" value from the string back to a Type variable and then using this Type variable to instruct GSON with loading of the actual "value" variable.

I do really like this system cause it lets me define property objects with different Object type variably on the fly whithout coding specific classes for specific Object Types.

**To my question now:**
Is there a "best practise" way to save and load Variables together with their Type?

When I coded this, I could not find any way to save a Type variable to file and load it.
At the moment, I am using a self written "decoder" to convert the saved Type-String back to a Type variable.

It feels like there should be an easier way to do this but I could not really find anything.

Thank you.

Comment: I like the question but I'd like to encourage you to share the encoder/decoder source code here so that we could know how it works for you, what it deals with, and how it can be improved. You didn't provide real details to talk about.

Comment: What comes to my mind is that you must be using `toString()` for `Type` instances and string parsers that can restore the type from its string representation. Many `Type` instances may be serializable so you can attempt to write/read them to/from object streams and encode/decode the binaries, say, to/from Base64. I guess the payload will be "too large" and probably incompatible between Java versions, but it would be more "native" and "out of box" solution.

Comment: I like the idea of serializable Type instances and will try that.
Also, I misremembered my code. I am using "valueType.toString()" for encoding.

To decode this String I am just going through it and read in each class seperately via "Class.forName()" and combine these classes according to their position in the string via "TypeToken.getParameterized()".
Regarding src. I don't really want to optimise this decoding process. I would rather want to know if there is an entirely different/better way of doing all of this.

Comment: Note that `Type` and `Class` are somewhat different therefore `Class.forName` may not work for other classes that implement `Type`. Say, `ParameterizedType` to-strings print type parameters, and `WildcardType` to-strings print generic types wildcards -- none of them can be handled by `Class.forName`, and you have to parse such strings including type parameters, arrays, type bounds to make it work properly. Worse, `toString()` may be not implemented, or implemented in another way, so even a custom "to-stringer" may be required.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no entirely different way: you'll always end up with a serialized represenation of types (it does not matter if it's a human-readable form or a binary object stream).

Comment: Yeah I already had problems with this earlier. I believe in Java 7 the type.toString() is differently implemented and prints out something like "class java.lang,String". In this case I am removing the "class " from the string. 
Thats also why I really hate the way I am doing this and wanted to know if there is a different way. 
But thanks for your help tho ^^.